# How does this expression work? ($variable/60) % 60

Tags: php, modulus

I understand how modulus works. It gives the remainder of the number. So 482 % 60 would give 2.

Can someone explain to me this expression:

```
$minutes = ($seconds/60) % 60;
```

To me this says:

```
if $seconds = 482

$minutes = (482/60) % 60
$minutes = (8.03333333333333) % 60
```

Then the result of that is 8. To me, it would have been simpler to leave out the % 60 part and just make 482/60 be an integer.  And I don't understand how the % 60 is operating in this case.

What am I missing?

Comment: `To me, it would have been simpler to leave out the % 60 part and just make 482/60 be an integer` What if `$seconds` is > 3600?

Comment: Thanks, that helps to clear it up.

Answer (score 2):

It gives you the minutes *without* the hours. Your example does not illustrate this as you are using seconds < 3600.

```
4000 seconds:
(seconds/60)%60
(4000/60)%60
(66.666)%60
```

6 minutes as a result. The 1 hour is calculated by another formula, most notably seconds/3600.

Comment: Actually hours would be, `(seconds/3600) % 24`, if you have days... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider if seconds was 3661.   You would have one hour, one minute, one second.   Your formula would have minutes as 61.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now!